# XXXX is no longer used. <see cref="EdmModelDiffer" /> is now used to detect changes in the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-4.3

In EF 4.3 `IncludeMetadataConvention`, `EdmMetadata` and other classes are obsolete:

> The XXX is no longer used. EdmMetadata is not
>   included in the model. <see cref="EdmModelDiffer" />
>   is now used to detect changes in the model.

What is `EdmModelDiffer` and how it should be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like `EdmModelDiffer` is an internal class for EF Code Migrations, so it is quite a bad error message to pass back to the user.

In Entity Framework 4.3 EF Migrations is used to detect changes in the model and optionally update the database when needed. [This](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/01/13/ef-4-3-beta-1-what-happened-to-that-edmmetadata-table/) blog post explains some details on edmmetadata vs the new ef migrations.

There are some EF migration walkthroughs (google for it) available as an introduction. I've written a [series](http://coding.abel.nu/series/ef-migrations) about it as well.

Comment: Here's the blog which prob. explain in much shortly and sweetly :) http://www.squarewidget.com/includemetadataconvention-deprecated-in-ef-4.3